# How to set servlet response code after catching error?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet, where my method gets data from db. I need to set server response code to 503 in case of an error.

My servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
          throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);

myMethod.getDataFromDb();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + ex);
      response.setStatus(503);
    }
  }
```

The code runs to catch block as i can get log from `System.out.println("Error: " + ex);`,
but the server still returns status as '200'. How to set the server response to '503' when there is an error?

Comment: Maybe in `processRequest()` there is some content already written to the response's output stream? `setStatus()` should be called before writing content. You can also try `setError()´.

Comment: This helped me to the correct solution. There was was a line in `processRequest()` that inttrupted the process.